# Linked List Stack in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I am looking at the following paragraph in the book "Programming Interviews Exposed" in reference to the implementation of a linked list stack in C:

```
typedef struct Element {
   struct Element *next;
   void *data; 
} Element;

void push( Element *stack, void *data ); 
void *pop( Element *stack );
```

> Now consider what will happen in these routines in terms of proper
>   functionality and error handling. Both operations change the first
>   element of the list. The calling routine’s stack pointer must be
>   modified to reflect this change, but any change you make to the
>   pointer that is passed to these functions won’t be propagated back to
>   the calling routine. You can solve this problem by having both
>   routines take a pointer to a pointer to the stack. This way, you can
>   change the calling routine’s pointer so that it continues to point at
>   the first element of the list. Implementing this change results in the
>   following:

```
void push( Element **stack, void *data ); 
void *pop( Element **stack);
```

Could someone explain, in different words, why we need to use a double pointer here? I'm a bit unsure about the explanation provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is similar to the famous swap() function in C.

Case 1:

```
void swapFails(int x, int y) {
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
```

Case 2:

```
void swapOk(int *x, int *y) {
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

and we invoke swap like this:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
```

Case 1:

```
swapFails(x, y);
```

Case 2:

```
swapOk(&x, &y);
```

Remember, we wanted to CHANGE the values of x and y. For CHANGING values of a datatype, we need pointers. Take this to the next level for pointers. For CHANGING values of a pointer, we would need double pointers.

For Stack using linked list:
If you push values 10, 20 and 30, they are stored like this:

```
top --- bottom
30 -> 20 -> 10
```

So you see every time you push or pop values from the stack, which is a linked list, the top or the first node of the linked list changes. Hence you need double pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The first version sends a `copy` of the pointer, if it's changed inside the function then the *local* copy would only be changed, when the function returns to the *caller* the caller still has a pointer to the *old* address.

```
Element *stack =...
push (stack)
void push( Element *stack, void *data ) {
  stack = ... // this changes the local pointer allocated on the function's stack
}
//call returns
stack //still points to old memory
```

The second version, however, passes a pointer to the stack pointer, so when that is changed, it changes the stack pointer in the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

In C everything is passed by value, let's say that I have this function:

```
void foo(void* ptr)
{
    ptr=NULL;
}
```

If you call this method in the main, the pointer that you pass will not be NULL (unless it wat already NULL).Because a copy of the pointer is made before passing it to the function.So if you want to modify it's value, you have to pass a double pointer:

```
void foo(void** ptr)
{
    *ptr=NULL;
}
```

The same is valid for the stack, of which you want to modify the value.

Answer (score 1):

With the single-pointer signature you can imagine using the code as follows

```
Element *myStack = NULL ;

.... bla bla bla ....

push(myStack, something);
```

Then in the `push` call you're telling the stack implementation where the *old* head element of the stack was, but there's no way for the implementation of `push` to tell you where the *new* head is. It cannot change your `myStack` variable, because parameter passing in C is always by value -- i.e., the `push` function get told what the *value* of `myStack` happens to be, but get no chance to change the caller's variable.

In order for things to work, you need to tell the push primitive the *address* of your local variable that it needs to change:

```
....
push(&myStack, something);
```

and since `myStack` itself has type `Element *`, a *pointer to* the `myStack` variable has type `Element **`.